# Retrieve the Id of recently inserted record

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, insert, identity

I currently have this SQL insert code in code behind

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim conString As String
conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnection").ConnectionString
con = New SqlConnection(conString)

con.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AdditionalDaysRequest(Status, AdditionalDays, Justification,RequestDaySubmitted) VALUES (@Status,@AdditionalDays,@Justification,@RequestDaySubmitted)", con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Pending Request")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdditionalDays", TB_Days.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Justification", TB_Justification.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestDaySubmitted", Date.Now)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

The `Id` in this table is automatically generated and incremented

What I would like to have now is the Id of this record inserted to add it to another table

Comment: Hi SeRo, What is the primary key of AdditionalDaysRequest table ?

Comment: Hi, The PK is the Id I'm trying to get, which is also auto-incremented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query text to add a second statement:

```
 ...;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

The SELECT [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) statement *Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope* as from the MSDN  article above.
In addition, you can use the ability of the Sql engine to understand and process two or more command statements passed as a single string if you separe the statements with a semicolon.
In this way you have the great benefit to execute *a single trip* to the database.

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AdditionalDaysRequest(Status, " & _ 
     "AdditionalDays, Justification,RequestDaySubmitted) VALUES " & _
     "(@Status,@AdditionalDays,@Justification,@RequestDaySubmitted);" & _ 
     "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con)

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Pending Request")
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdditionalDays", TB_Days.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Justification", TB_Justification.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestDaySubmitted", Date.Now)
 Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
 con.Close()     
 if result IsNot Nothing Then

       Dim lastInsertId = Convert.ToInt32(result)

 End If
```

Notice that the two statements are now executed using `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` because we want to catch the result of the last command.

Comment: Perfect answer mate. Appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

You will want to run a new SqlCommand.  Set the value of lastInsertId with this statement:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an additional knowledge.

we have multiple options like:

```
@@IDENTITY
SCOPE_IDENTITY
IDENT_CURRENT
```

All three functions return last-generated identity values. However

IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

@@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.